# Alert running many number of times using plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on this plugin

HTML

```
<span class="item" data-item="first">
</span>   
<br><br>  

<span class="item" data-item="second">
</span>    
<br><br>    

<span class="item" data-item="third">
</span>
```

JQUERY

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){    
    return this.each(function(){

          for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            $(this).append('<span class="act" title="active '+i+'">act'+i+'</span><br>');
        }        

          $('.act').bind({
        mouseover :function(){  
          var item=$(this).parent().attr('data-item');
          alert(item);               
        }             

      });          

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.item').myPlugin();

});
```

When i hover on act it fires alert 3 times ie. the number of .item present below it. Whats the problem here?

Demo http://jsbin.com/IWutoQa/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a mouseover handler to each `.act` element in every loop. Instead, use a single delegated handler:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
        $(this).on('mouseover', '.act', function(){  
            var item = $(this).parent().attr('data-item');
            alert(item);           
        });    

        return this.each(function() {    
            for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                $(this).append('<span class="act" title="active '+i+'">act'+i+'</span><br>');
            }   
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').myPlugin();
});
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/IWutoQa/6/edit)

Comment: Will it be a problem if i use bind? cause a have many events . And which elements should i put in ` return this.each(function() {})` and which outside ?

Comment: Would it not be better to use `$(this)` rather than `$('.item')` to register the mouseover event?

Comment: You need to use `on` with a delegated selector. Because you are appending elements after the DOM has loaded, so using `bind()` in my example would not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have 4 -5 events to call so i should do it using `on` for every event or there is another way?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan which one is better approach , bind event to every item on which plugin is applied `oGeez` method  or the one you used using `on` ?

Comment: @Ace the one I used - `on()` - will be quicker. It binds a single event, instead of `x` events per `.act` element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you used `$('.item').on('mouseover'` wont it limit the plugin to class `.item` only? got confused after your explanation to Nunners. can i use $(this) instead like Nunner used?

Comment: Sorry, yes you can use `$(this)`, I was being dumb.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding to every `.act` element, you are inside an `each()` method so you are already looping through items. You only need to bind the `.act` of the **current** item in the loop, one way is to use `$(this)` with `children()`:

```
$(this).children('.act').bind({
  mouseover :function(){  
  var item=$(this).parent().attr('data-item');
  alert(item);
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/IWutoQa/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You are appending an `act` span to each of the `item` spans when you load your plugin. For every act span you are then binding the mouseover event that fires an alert. You should bind the event by ID instead of Class if you only want this to occur once.

i.e. Appended HTML becomes :

```
$(this).append('<span id="act'+i+'" class="act" title="active '+i+'">act'+i+'</span><br>');
```

And you then bind the event in for loop against ID.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    $(this).append('<span id="act'+i+'" class="act" title="active '+i+'">act'+i+'</span><br>');
    $('#act' + i).bind({
        mouseover :function(){  
          var item=$(this).parent().attr('data-item');
          alert(item);               
        }
    });
}
```